# If I run both of these Anaconda PATH commands, will it still work fine if I choose to use either version?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

for anaconda 2 :

```
export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

for anaconda 3 :

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

I read somewhere to use these two commands, however I have installed both anaconda 2 & 3 but I would just like to use the conda command. I ran the top command first, followed by the second. Then I read somewhere that I can run the same command but without the number 2 or 3 behind it, and I thought I should have done that.

Since I didn't do that, and ran both commands one after another instead, will it still work fine if I ran the conda command on either Python 2 or Python 3?

Do ask me further if I'm confusing you.

Comment: What is the output of "which python"?

Comment: How do I check for that?

Comment: Open a command prompt and type "which python" and copy/paste the output

Comment: This is what I go: /home/kaichongwong/anaconda3/bin/python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. It seems from the output of "which python" that your default Python is Python 3.

You can easily use multiple Python versions by creating environments natively through conda. You can create an environment like this:

```
conda create --name py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

And activate the environment like this:

```
source activate py27
```

Comment: Thank you so much!